# How to simulate StackExchange Inbox notification

Tags: discussion, notifications, global-inbox

I really like this circle with number inside of it. It's awesome way to show new messages in non offensive. I want to create similar notification UX for some eGovernment portal.
How can I create this in css. I know I can inspect css with Google chrome or firebug, but currently I have no notification in my inbox :/ to analyse this html & css.

[image: Notification Inbox]

Comment: you'd probably be better off asking this question on stackoverflow instead of meta.

Comment: Ok, I asked here because I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605291/header-message-just-like-at-stack-overflow which was not closed as off topic. You can move to main SO, no problem, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

#### CSS:

```
.unreadCount{
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background-color:#e23535;
    color:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:2px 4px;
    font-size:9px;
    margin:3px 0 0 -117px;
 }
```

Comment: yes, now I see it :) got the inbox notifications, thanks

Comment: use `border-radius:50%;` rather than `10px;` for a circle that scales to whatever size your font is.